# Get data from Oracle to SQL server after Oracle statements is excuted

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm making a project with SQL Server but I just can get data from Oracle database in my customer's PC. Because they want to manage data before i can do with it. I have used Linked Server of Microsoft and Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle to get data from Oracle database. But I have a problem I dont know when my customer INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE Oracle records. Is there anyway to migrate data from Oracle automatically to my SQL Server?

Really need a help. I have to manual do it everytime I want to update SQL Server database to get new records from Oracle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A scheduled job is probably as good as it gets here.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Can you give me more explaination?